# Multiple data labels (or multi-line labels) above bars in Plotly

Tags: plotly, plotly.js

Is it possible to add multiple text labels, or equivalently, multi-line text labels in Plotly using the official JSON API?

I tried entering labels as arrays, strings with `<br/>`, `&#x10;`, `\n`, etc. to no avail.  My fallback option is to render it with some delimiter and then use D3 to break the  into multiple lines.

The blue text below is what Id like, the grey text is what I;m getting.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Almost!

In python you need to use `</br></br>` but should work for you too :)

Reproducible example:

*(Made it for chart title, plots titles, legends, xlabels... But should work for everything else.)*

```
from plotly.subplots import make_subplots
import plotly.graph_objects as go

fig = make_subplots(rows=2, subplot_titles=("Plot</br></br>Number 1", "Plot</br></br>Number 2"))

fig.add_scatter(y=[2, 1, 3], row=1, col=1, name='TEST</br></br>HEHE') 
fig.add_scatter(y=[1, 3, 2], row=2, col=1, name='TEST2</br></br>HEHE')

fig.update_xaxes(tickmode='array',
                tickvals=[0,1,2,3],
                ticktext=['AAA</br></br>AAA','BBB</br></br>BBB', 'CCC</br></br>CCC'])

fig.update_layout(title_text='Your title</br></br>here', showlegend=True)
```

Output:

(*Don't know why my uploaded pic looks more like a thumbnail than an image. Click on it to zoom in.*)

[image]

Comment: Perfect, this works in Javascript too.  Strangely you need a double `</br></br>` for the first line break, then just one `</br>` for each line break thereafter.

Comment: Glad to hear that! Yes that's kinda weird because back in the time I was facing this problem, I remember I couldn't find anything in the official documentation. IIRC I found the trick in a "Issues"comment on a GitHub.